# Redux denormalizr

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using a thunk for getting data async from an API, this is nested data like this:

```
{
  person: {
      id: <id>
      services: [{
        id: <id>,
        leader: {
          id: <id>,
          name: <name>
        }
      },...]
  }
}
```

Now, this gets normalized into this (let's imagine we have a bunch of persons and stuff):

```
{
  result: <person-id-1>,
  entities: {
    person: {
      <person-id-1> : { 
        services: [<service-id-1>,...]
      },...
    },
    service: {
      <service-id-1>: {
        leader: <leader-id-1>
      }
    },
    leader: {
      <leader-id-1>: {
        name: <name>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Ok, so, now I've to get this entity full into my component, the question is, **What's the best way to do this?**

- Should construct this entity back into the function `mapStateToProps`
- Should I do it into the `render()` method,
- In any case, what's the best approach for this. I've seen the [reselect library](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) but I still not very sure that this is the solution for getting the entity back together. Also there are other libraries to denormalize the entities, but not sure if I should use them.
- Should I just create a nested component for each nested entity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the standard approach is to do any data shaping for a given component in its `mapState` function, using Reselect-based selectors to memoize the process.  You may also want to look into the [Redux-ORM](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm) library, which provides a very nice abstraction layer over managing normalized data in a Redux store.  I use it for both data de-normalization/selection in thunks and `mapState` functions, and immutable data updating in reducers.

There's also a good article on this topic at https://medium.com/@adamrackis/querying-a-redux-store-37db8c7f3b0f .

Answer (score 1):

You should check [this video](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-normalizing-the-state-shape?course=building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux) made by the Redux author and the [shopping cart](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/shopping-cart) example in redux repo. `reselect` helps you to create an memoized, composable selector functions. read more [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html#). I hope it will help you.